# React Redux mapStateToProps loads data in the second call

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

mapStatToProps is callings it's self twice and loads data on the second call but then doesn't assign it to components as a prop and returns an empty array.

The Reducer:

```
 export default function postsReducer(state = initialState.posts, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_POSTS_SUCCESS:
      return action.posts;
    default:
      return state;
  }
 }
```

Here is my mpStateToProps func:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
     const singlePost = state.posts.filter(post => post.code == ownProps.params.id);
      return {
        post: singlePost
     };
   }
```

Here is my Component's state:

```
this.state = {
   post: [...props.post]
};
```

Comment: is `state.posts` an array of arrays or why are you doing `state.posts[0].filter` instead of `state.posts.filter`?

Comment: @webdeb Sorry the state.posts[0].filter should be state.posts.filter, I made a mistake in posting the code here but the issue is still the same.
P.S code updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is probably right, but it seems like you forgot to update your state.post value when your component receives new props.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    post: nextProps.post
  });
}
```